# Center align button with bootstrap

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I am getting stuck about aligning some buttons on line and all centered with bootstrap.

I have created the following [bootply sample](http://www.bootply.com/d9mwUbLbtb).
Why do the buttons stack vertically and not horizontally?

Also, I have to mix simple buttons with code like the following

```
@Html.ActionLink( "REGISTER", "LoginRegister", "Account", new { LoginTabActive = false, RegisterTabActive = true }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg center-block" } )
```

which generates the following markup

```
<a href="/Account/LoginRegister?LoginTabActive=False&amp;RegisterTabActive=True" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg center-block">REGISTER</a>
```

In this case the button will expand to occupy all the horizontal space.

Comment: Try this: http://www.bootply.com/k1AW0VTMuX#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add Bootstrap's `text-center` class to your menuArea div.

**[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/NTHzvtoAFs)**

**HTML**:

```
<div class="menubar" style="background-color: #0055b8; color:#ffffff; height: 30px;">
    <h3 class="text-center">menu bar title</h3>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#topMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="topMenu">
        <span class="chevron_toggleable glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="topMenu">
    <div class="menuArea text-center">
            <button id="mybutton" name="mybutton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">1</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button id="mybutton2" name="mybutton2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">2</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button id="mybutton3" name="mybutton3" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, you need to add "text-center" to your menuArea div, and remove the "center-block" from each button element.

http://www.bootply.com/wpAjCqxV3c